# DeathAnimation spawn in World Center (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Everytime an enemy dies the DeathAnimation spawns in the world center and not where the enemy died.[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgo1c.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using `Enemy.transform.localPosition`. Try printing the result of that to make sure it's the location of the enemy and not `0, 0, 0`. If it is, you can just use `Enemy.transform.position`,